# How to generate programmatically Horizontal scrolling LinearLayout with Imageview and textview at center bottom

Tags: android, xml

I want to generate programmatically Horizontal scrolling LinearLayout with Imageview and textview at center bottom.

this is my Java code.:

```
      LinearLayout rec=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.hori_recom);

     //ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=new   ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(450,450);
      ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      // for(int g=0;g<5;g++)
      for(int g=0;g<imgpath_orignal.size();g++)
      {

        ImageView recimg=new ImageView(Details.this);
        recimg.setId(g+1);
        recimg.setPadding(25,0,0,0);
        Picasso.with(Details.this).load(al_gallary_img.get(g)).placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .error(R.drawable.logo).into(recimg);
        recimg.setLayoutParams(params);
        TextView txtlabel=new TextView(Details.this);
        txtlabel.setId(g+1);
        txtlabel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.BOTTOM);
        txtlabel.setPadding(15,15,15,15);
        txtlabel.setText(""+al_img_caption.get(g));
        txtlabel.setLayoutParams(params1);
        rec.addView(txtlabel);
        rec.addView(recimg);
```

This is my Xml:

```
           <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">


                 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/hori_recom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

         </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Problem is I am not getting my textview at bottom-center of my Imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing - combine your `ImageView` and `TextView` in one layout

Say this layout as `row_layout`.

```
<LinearLayout
    ....
    ....

    <ImageView
        ...
        ... />
    <TextView
        ...
        ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now add Layout into the `LinearLayout` which lies into `HorizontalScrollView` -

```
for(int g=0; g<imgpath_orignal.size(); g++) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    // Do your layout binding stuff over here..
    ImageView ivPhoto = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageview_id); // Give reference
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(ivPhoto); // Loading image using Picasso
    rec.addView(v);
}
```

Comment: Sir I am new in android development will you please suggest how to bind Imageview and Textview to new inflated layout.

Comment: I have done something like this :  LayoutInflater inflater = Details.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null, true); LinearLayout view_custom=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.view_custom); view_custom.addView(recimg);
            view_custom.addView(txtlabel); but it crash

Comment: See how I did `findViewById()` stuff, I've edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set gravity of TextView as center_bottom instead of layout_gravity.

Just remove

```
txtlabel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

and instead of

`` ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1 = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);` ``

do this

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.BOTTOM;`

This is the way of setting layout_gravity programatically.

Comment: It give's output as textview at bottam but not textview below imageview.